# Why didn't Sabrina know about the Feast of Feasts?

Tags: chilling-adventures-of-sabrina

Sabrina's aunts called the Feast of Feasts an annual celebration, meaning it's occurred over a dozen since Sabrina was born. It involves fourteeen families from the local group of witches, which seems to be a relatively small, insular group, in a fairly small town to begin with. It's unclear whether it's always the same 14 (in which case the Spellmans have always been a part of it).

However, when her aunts tell her about it, she reacts with shock, suggesting that she didn't know about it. Further, other students know about it (such as the weird sisters).

Why had Sabrina not heard about this tradition before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sabrina supposedly has a free will choice to follow either the Path of the Light or the Path of the Night, because she's a hybrid. Since she has human emotions, and thus some sense of morality, most of the evil stuff witches would be forced to do is hidden away from her. Dealing with demons, giving your soul to the Dark One, loss of free will, human sacrifice and blood rituals, etc, are all hidden from her to try and make the upsides of being on the Path of the Night more attractive than the powerless Path of the Light followers.

Her humanity revolts against those ideas, trying to help people that are being bullied or hurt, and she comes to learn that she'll not only be forbidden from helping people, but will actively be forced to hurt people, even perhaps people she loves or feels sorry for. Since she's already been foretold as being the most powerful witch alive, or even perhaps ever (we're not told exactly what, but it's implied), it's important that the Dark One gets her under control any way possible. Hiding this information from her was a 16 year deception aimed to try and get her to commit to being the Dark Lord's slave.

Basically, she didn't know, because she would have chosen the Path of the Light in a heartbeat, and the Dark One's plans would have been ruined, or at least significantly delayed, since ultimately it was her humanity that leads her to make the decision that she did make. The Dark One was simply trying to use persuasion instead of force, since it was the path of least resistance.

Comment: I see...so her aunts went along with this because they were faithful Satanists, in essence?

Comment: @Adamant Hilda might have told her if she had more backbone, but since Zelda tended to murder her for transgressions, she was reluctant to try anything (at least, that's the feeling I get). There's a lot left unexplained that I think will show up in Part 2, but yes, the summary is that all witches over the age of 16 were not going to try and tell her, since the Dark One especially wanted her for her potential power.

Answer (score -2):

Because the audience didn't know. Even though she was raised in the witch world she is being used as surrogate for the audience to know things. That's why she knows all the languages required for spell work but doesn't know what a Malum Malice is.

Comment: That's not really an explanation within the context of the story.